# Best practice: database referencing tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

In database design what are the feelings of tuple vs referencing table for small pieces of data?

For instance, supposing you are designing a schema involving office management. You want to record what department each employee belongs to, but are otherwise uninterested in any information relating to departments. So do you have department as a string/char/varchar/etc in your EMPLOYEE table, or have it instead be a foreign key, relating a DEPARTMENT table.

If the DEPARTMENT table is recording nothing other than department names, one would normally want to combine this with the EMPLOYEE table. But if this is contained in the EMPLOYEE table you cannot guarantee that some users will call HR "HumanResourses", some may call it "H-R", some may call it "human resources", etc. Having it as a foreign key guarantees that it can be only one thing. Also, if other information is ever to be added about departments, it would be easy if it is in a table of its own.

So what do people think about it? Naturally more tables and referencing is also likely to have a negative impact on performance. My question specifically is asked with Oracle 11g in mind, but I doubt that the type of rdms involved has much bearing on this design consideration.

Comment: I think you answered your own question:   "if this is contained in the EMPLOYEE table you cannot guarantee that some users will call HR 'HumanResourses', some may call it 'H-R', some may call it "human resources", etc"...have you deturmined that you actually need to worry about performance at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the related table, then you don't have the performance problem of updating 1,000,000 records because the Personnel Department became the Human Resources department.

You have another option. Create the table and use it as a lookup for data entry. But store the information in the main table.

However, I prefer the option of using the related table for the departments and storing the ID for the department and the employee in a join table that has the ids and start and endates. Over time employees tend to move from one department to another. It is helpful for reporting to be able to tell what department they were in when. You need to consider how the data will be used over time and in reporting when designing this sort of thing. Short-sighted designs are hard to fix later.

Your concern about having too many tables is really unfounded. Databases are designed to have many tables and to use joins. If you **index** correctly, there will not be preformance implications for most databases. And you know what,I know of realtional database with many many tables that have terrabytes of data that perform just fine.

Comment: FWIW, I tested cascading updates the other day on my desktop computer. It cascaded updates to 3 million rows in a table of 50 million rows in less than 3 seconds.  (PostgreSQL 9.1. The computer isn't anything particularly fast or special.) I don't think I've worried about the speed of cascading updates for years.  So I agree with "more tables", but don't *always* agree with "use an ID number". +1

Answer (score 2):

You only have to worry about the performance impact of this sort of thing if you're dealing with truly massive datasets. For any regular office environment system like this, prefer the normalized schema.